# ServiceMix can't start

Tags: java, startup, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

My serviceMix can't start, i juste trying to stop it ./stop then./start

when i do ./client :

```
client: JAVA_HOME not set; results may vary
Logging in as smx
Failed to get the session.
```

My JAVA_HOME is set correctlly.

when i do ./status

```
karaf: JAVA_HOME not set; results may vary
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256M; support was removed in 8.0
Not Running ...
```

when i do ./stop

```
karaf: JAVA_HOME not set; results may vary
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256M; support was removed in 8.0
Can't connect to the container. The container is not running.
```

Before I stop it functioned normally.

thx for your help

Comment: What version of Servicemix are you using?

Comment: I use Apache ServiceMix 5.4.0

Comment: including : Apache ActiveMQ 5.10.0 // Apache Camel 2.14.1 // Apache CXF 3.0.2 // Apache Karaf 2.4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying configuring the JAVA_HOME setting in servicemix's bin/setenv file.

In the file, you will find a section looking something like the follow. Trying setting JAVA_HOME here.

> # general settings which should be applied for all scripts go here; please keep in mind that it is possible that scripts might be executed more than once, e.g. in example of the start script where the start script is executed first and the karaf script afterwards.
>
> # The following section shows the possible configuration options for the default karaf scripts
>
> # export JAVA_HOME # Location of Java installation

Comment: Ok, I have configure again the JAVA_HOME and now when i do ./client : Logging in as smx
Failed to get the session.

Comment: Did you start servicemix yet? The client is used to log into an already running instance of servicemix.

Comment: Try running bin/servicemix rather than bin/client.

Comment: when i do : ./servicemix : Please wait while Apache ServiceMix is starting... (now 20min) without response

Comment: Is this a fresh install of servicemix you are using? Will you go to the data/log directory, open up servicemix.log, and read over the latest lines. Can you post them?

Comment: Log : Apr 04, 2016 2:58:44 PM org.apache.karaf.main.SimpleFileLock lock
INFO: locking

Comment: I meant, can you copy and paste, say, the last 50 lines of the file as an edit to your original question above.

Comment: all log lines it's same : all line : "PM org.apache.karaf.main.SimpleFileLock lock
"

Comment: msaidi@msaidi-DevPost:/ke/local/servicemix/data/log$ cat servicemix.log 
Apr 04, 2016 2:58:15 PM org.apache.karaf.main.SimpleFileLock lock
INFO: locking
Apr 04, 2016 2:58:15 PM org.apache.karaf.main.Main doLock
INFO: Waiting for the lock ...
Apr 04, 2016 2:58:16 PM org.apache.karaf.main.SimpleFileLock lock
INFO: locking
Apr 04, 2016 2:58:17 PM org.apache.karaf.main.SimpleFileLock lock
....

Comment: Got it. What version of Java are you running? What operating system? If you are on Linux, can you run the following command `ps aux | grep servicemix` and tell me if there is an instance of servicemix running.

Comment: yea I have a instance running : the response for the cmd is very large but i send you an example for response : ps aux | grep servicemix
msaidi     877  0.0  2.8 2928960 115472 ?      Sl   Apr01   3:24 /usr/bin/java -server -Xms128M -Xmx512M -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+UnsyncloadClass -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/jre/lib/endorsed:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/endorsed:/ke/local/servicemix/lib/endorse

Comment: yea i have a servicemix instance running , I have Java 8 and servicemix 5.4.0

Comment: Alright. The reason you are getting the "Please wait while Apache Servicemix is starting..." message is because there is already another instance running. Kill the instance of servicemix that is currently running. Once you have killed the running instance, run ./bin/servicemix again. It should start now.

Comment: yess !!! many process stopped (i think i launched many process) but that's okay now , thx man :)

Comment: No problem! Just so you know. When you run ./bin/servicemix, you are launching servicemix within your current shell. When you close your shell, it will kill the servicemix process. If you are looking to keep servicemix running, event when you close your shell, use .bin/start to start servicemix and then use .bin/client to log into the instance. To stop the servicemix instance that is running in the background, use .bin/stop